# Python でのパッケージ雛形作成の定番は?

Tags: python

Python でのパッケージ雛形作成をしてくれるようなツールでよいものがあれば教えてください。
Perl や Ruby でいえば [Minilla](https://metacpan.org/pod/Minilla) や [Bundler](https://rubygems.org/gems/bundler) の `bundle gem` コマンドに相当するようなものを考えています。

現在は [python_boilerplate_template](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python_boilerplate_template) の `paster` を利用していますが、作りたいパッケージが `src/{{ egg_name }}` のように1段深いディレクトリに作成されるのが少しおおげさで、不満を感じています。

Answer (score 9, accepted):

大掛かりなテンプレートでなく basic_package テンプレートなら、直下のディレクトリにトップレベルパッケージが作成されるようです。

```
paster -t basic_package
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。paster 自身は [PasteScript](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PasteScript/) 由来で、私がおおげさに感じていたテンプレートは [python_boilerplate_template](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python_boilerplate_template) によるもので PasteScript 付属の basic_package テンプレートを使えばいいんですね。